# Compare multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a spec I want to compare two multi-dimensional arrays:

```
array1 = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]
array2 = [["b"]]
expect(array1).to include(array2)
```

But it returns:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(array1).to include(array2)
       expected [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]] to include [["b"]]
```

Also this results in the same error:

```
array1 = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]
array2 = array1
expect(array1).to include(array2)
```

So how can I compare these two arrays?

Comment: I believe it should be an element no an array : `expected [["a"], ["b"], ["c"]] to include(["b"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`include?` method](http://array1%20=%20[[%22a%22],[%22b%22],[%22c%22]]%20array2%20=%20[[%22b%22]]%20expect(array1).to%20include(array2)) tests the param against *members* of the array so you'd have to test with the `['b']` element of `array2` only:

```
array1 = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]
array2 = [["b"]]
expect(array1).to include(array2.first)
# => should pass
```

If there might be more than a single element in the second array, you might use an intersection of the two arrays:

```
array1 = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]
array2 = [["a"], ["b"]]
expect(array1 & array2).to eq(array2)
# => should pass

array1 = [["a"],["b"],["c"]]
array2 = [["a"], ["e"]]
expect(array1 & array2).to eq(array2)
# => should fail
```